# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on setCollectionViewLayout

Tags: iphone, ios, exc-bad-access, uicollectionview

If I change the layout of a [UICollectionView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionView) during an orientation change, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` after a few rotations.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    UICollectionViewLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    self.myCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout; // This causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS after a few rotations
}
```

Is this a `UICollectionView` bug? Or am I doing something wrong? If it's a bug, is there any way to change the whole layout during an orientation change?

I noticed that the same problem is mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631040/143378). Debugging with NSZombies does not produce additional information.

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I'm having a similar issue with changing the layout using `[collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:layout animated:animated]`.  The backtrace looks like: `* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x01780098 libobjc.A.dylib\`objc_msgSend + 12, stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc0000000)
    frame #0: 0x01780098 libobjc.A.dylib\`objc_msgSend + 12
    frame #1: 0x008f6ed5 UIKit\`-[UICollectionViewData _setLayoutAttributes:atGlobalItemIndex:] + 62
    frame #2: 0x008f80f6 UIKit\`__45-[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:]_block_invoke_0 + 1004`

Comment: Probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786084/uicollectionview-bad-acces-on-uicollectionviewdata-setlayoutattributesatglo, also still open.

Comment: Is there a UIDynamicAnimator using this layout, by any chance? (**Edit:** I suppose not, if this was posted 10 months ago.)

Comment: Exactly the same issue and backtrace. I am changing the layout when rotating the device. But in my case, I cannot reproduce even if it is top one crash reported by users of my app.

Comment: i still have the same stack trace. i'm still unable to fix this issue. Someone solved it ?

Comment: Are you changing the dataSource while changing the layout? In my case, change layout before change data source can avoid crash.

Comment: Still suffering from this guy almost a year later!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure it has something to do but the [Release Notes for iOS 6](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/_index.html) say:

> The `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`,
>   `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, and
>   `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` methods are no longer called on any
>   view controller that makes a full-screen presentation over itself—for
>   example, `presentViewController:animated:completion:`
>
> You should make sure that your apps are not using these methods to manage the layout of any subviews. Instead, they should use the view
>   controller’s `viewWillLayoutSubviews` method and adjust the layout using
>   the view’s bounds rectangle.

Since you are using `UICollectionView` *maybe* it has something to do that you are using this method to change its layout.

Comment: I believe this is not the case, as the view controller in question is the main view controller and not presented via presentViewController:animated:completion:.